# HTML/CSS: a:hover {-webkit/-moz-transition:color}

Tags: html, css

When I mouse over a list element, the transition occurs correctly, however when I mouse over (hover over) a list element with a link the text will not transition until I specifically mouse over the text itself.

Here's a GIF of the problem(sorry for the lack of a cursor -- 'Home' is a link within a list and 'example1' is merely a list):

[image]

It strikes me I may be a bit vague here. [Here it is uploaded in its current form](http://www.clutchhunter.appspot.com/experimental.html) - the CSS responsible for that navbar is within the /* dropdown */ boxes.

The source in its entirety is all there on that webpage if you inspect element. (I tried putting it here but the code tag is refusing to work.)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have space between your `li` and your `a` tag.  You need to apply all styling in your submenu to the `a` tag, not to the `li`.

So, instead of having

```
li {
    padding:5px
}
```

have

```
li a {
   padding: 5px
}
```

do something similar with your hover.  Attach the hover class to the `a`, not the `li`.

Edit:

alternatively, specify the `:hover { color :#fff; }` to the `li` (it is currently on the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It's often good to have your anchor elements occupy the complete space of the menu item. This serves two purposes:

1. It can react to events anywhere in the area.
2. Users don't have to "hunt" to find the clickable/touchable region.

Specifically, I'd suggest setting the display of your anchors to `block` or `inline-block`, and padding them (not the containing `<li>` elements).

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/zzjZY/3/

**CSS**

```
LI {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
A {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}
A:hover {
    -webkit-transition:color 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:color 300ms ease-in-out;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#060;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">a little text</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">a little text</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">a little text</a></li>
</ul>
```

You will see that the `:hover` formatting is applied anywhere inside the containing element, because the anchor fills it completely. The link is also clickable anywhere inside the containing list item.